# PHP Error Undefined Offset, SQL Export tool

Tags: php

I keep getting the error:

PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /home/mydomain/mydomain.com/admin/model/tool/export_xls.php on line 150

I've looked at the other similar posts but none of those resolutions work on my code. I don't see any numbers related to the array, and I've double checked for missing closing } . I asked the code developer and all he did was get it to stop displaying the error, but it still shows up (several thousand times) in my error log. line 150 is the blank line above the code

"//Get all options values to each option"

Code:

```
public function get_all_options()
    {
        $this->load->model('catalog/option');
        $all_options = $this->model_catalog_option->getOptions();

        $options_final = array();

        //Format options
        foreach ($all_options as $key => $op) {
            $options_final[$op['name'].'_'.$op['type']] = array(
                'option_id' => $op['option_id'],
                'option_name' => $op['name'],
                'option_values' => array()
            );
        }

        //Get all options values to each option
        foreach ($options_final as $option_name => $op) {
            $option_values = $this->model_catalog_option->getOptionValues($op['option_id']);

            //Format option values
            $option_values_final = array();

            foreach ($option_values as $key => $op) {
                $option_values_final[$op['name']] = $op['option_value_id'];
            }

            $options_final[$option_name]['option_values'] = $option_values_final;
        }

        return $options_final;         
    }
```

Comment: So this code is line 151 and on? Can you show the code before/up to line 150 (we don't need all 150 lines, just some)

Comment: No this is lines 135-167. line 150 is the blank line after     'option_values' => array()
    );
   } above the code

"//Get all options values to each option"

Comment: Blank lines don’t throw such errors.

Comment: You'd think so, I'm guessing that means that there is something is missing, but I don't see any unclosed brackets or parenthesis.

Comment: So here's what's really weird, is the guy who wrote this bit of code can run it through the website and not get any errors and get actual output, but when I run it through the same website against the same sql tables I get the errors.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are accessing an array which index is not set . try something like this

```
    //Format options

    foreach ($all_options as $key => $op) {
        $options_final[$op['name'].'_'.$op['type']] 
      = array(
         'option_id' =>isset($op['option_id']) ? 
     :$op['option_id']:null,     
     'option_name' => isset($op['option_name']) 
     ? :$op['option_name']:null,                
    'option_values' => array()
        );
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, im getting errors on 3 lines          ':$op['option_id']:null,      ? :$op['option_name']:null, and         );'